# Magento filter collection by attribute option

Tags: php, magento, filter

I'm pretty new to Magento and I'm trying to figure out how to filter a collection of products. Here's the situation: I have a product that have a 'style', which is a product's attribute (example of style: brass). I need to get all other products that have the style 'brass'.

I've done a few research and discovered the addFieldToFilter() method, but it doesn't seem to be working (or, most likely, I'm not using it properly):

```
$same_style_collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter(array(array('attribute' => 'name', 'like' => 'brass')));
```

Can anyone help me? It would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried like this?

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('style', 'brass');
```

This will give you all the products which have an attribute `style` with value `brass`.

When you want to filter data from EAV collection you use `addAttributeToFilter`, and when you want to filter data from Flat table collection you use `addFieldToFilter`.

Comment: That didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                        ->getCollection()
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

foreach ($collection as $product) {


    echo $product->getName() . "<br />";

    }
```

With such getter setter methods you can access every product attributes like I have done here.